# Sign convention in lenses and mirrors

Tags: optics, conventions, geometric-optics, lenses

Can we change the sign convention (distance measured in the direction of incident ray positive and opposite negative) midway solving a problem. According to me we should ,as the mirror/lens formula is for an individual apparatus,and cannot be for the whole problem.

$-----------------------------------------------------------$

An example of the above concept 
[image]

[image]
In this arrangement, a ray of light
Is first refracted by lens L. then at
 reflected at curved mirror M. and finally refracted once again at lens
L. Let object O be located in front
of the lens. Let the image from lens
$l_1$, be formed at $v_1$Then. from the
lens- formula we have $\frac{1}{v_1} -\frac 1u =\frac{1}{f_l1}$
(i)

where $f_l1$ is.
the focal length Of  the Iens L when the ray
approaches from the left.
$I_1$will now be the object for mirror M. Let image $I_2$ be formed
after reflection at $v_2$ from the pole of the mirror. Then.

$\frac{1}{v_2} + \frac{1}{v_1} = \frac{1}{f_m}$.  (ii)

where $f_m,$ is the focal length of mirror M.
Now, $I_2$ will be the object for the final refraction at lens L.
If $I_3$ be the final image formed at v from the center of the lens,

Then we have .
(iii)
$\frac 1v - \frac{1}{v_2} = \frac{1}{f_l2}$

where fl2. is the focal length of the lens, L when the ray
of light approaches from the right. When a ray of light
approaches from the left. the positive X-axis is from Is from left to
right.

Is it were replaced by a concave mirror today focal length $f_e$ then

$\frac 1v + \frac 1u =\frac{1}{f_e}$

On solving  we get $f_e =f_m$

This is definitely wrong.

I think problem is somewhere with the sign convention in the last refraction. 
As for last refraction coordinate system cannot be same as in the first refraction and reflection convention is positive towards right. So what will be the new mirror formulae. 
By hit and trial it comes out to that simply replace f>-f 
But according to me if convention is reversed ( right is negative and left is positive ) lens formula becomes. 
$-\frac 1v - (-\frac 1u) =- \frac 1f $

Which is actually the same formulae ??
I am terribly confused in such a simple problem .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Varang and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: You should find equivalent power instead of focal length as power of converging system,either convex lens or concave mirror,has same sign.

Comment: I think this question doesn't run afoul of our homework policy, since it seems to be asking a conceptual question about why a derivation doesn't work, not asking for the answer to the homework question. That being said, it would probably benefit from some editing to clarify that.

Comment: @JohnRennie :It isn't a worked type problem. I came up with the above derivation on my own and it will definitely help somebody looking for new lens formula when sign convention is not followed. ;)